# php run multiple query with one database tool

Tags: php, postgresql

I have php web application and I use PostgreSQL for database.
I have a method that need multiple query to db. Like following:

```
function recheck($id){
    $pgDB = new PostgreDB();
    $response = FALSE;
    $rows = $pgDB->selectRow('table', array('id'=>intval($id)));
    if (!count($rows)) {
        $response = 'Error';
    }
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $recheck = $this->gateUtil->recheck($row);
        if (!$recheck) {
            $pgDB->updateRow('table', array("stage"=>-1), array("id"=>intval($id)));
            $response = 'Did not confirmed.';
        } else {
            $updateRes = $pgDB->updateRow('table', array("stage"=>1), array("id"=>intval($id)));
            if ($updateRes) {
                $response = 'Request recheck confirmed!';
            } else {
                $response = 'Something went wrong!';
            }
        }
    }
    $pgDB->close();
    return $response;
}
```

updateRow method:

```
function updateRow($table, $values, $where=NULL) {
        ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $qry = $this->buildQueryUpdate($table, $values, $where);
        $res = pg_query($this->handler, $qry);
        $ret = TRUE;
        if (!$res) $ret = FALSE;
//      pg_free_result($res);
        return $ret;
    }
```

selectRow method:

```
function selectRow($table, $where=NULL, $columns=NULL, $order=NULL, $isAsc=TRUE, $limit=NULL, $offset=NULL) {
        $qry = $this->buildQuerySelect($table, $where, $columns, $order, $isAsc, $limit, $offset);
        $res = pg_query($this->handler, $qry);
        $ret = array();
        while ($row=pg_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $ret[] = $row;
        }
//      pg_free_result($res);
        return $ret;
    }
```

It works ok for selectRow method but in updateRow method it returns following warnings and errors:

> **Warning**:  pg_query(): 48 is not a valid PostgreSQL link
>   resource in **/var/www/html/lib/postgresql.class.php** on line
>   **69**

And line 69 is:

```
$res = pg_query($this->handler, $qry);
```

when I echo or print_r $this->handler before and after this line it is both

> Resource id #48

The only codes that is out of your sight is $this->gateUtil->recheck($row); and recheck method does nothing with db and only checks so that some strings be at right size.
I don't know what is the problem. I've tested all kind of possibilities and all failed...
please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these functions you show us actually class methods?

Comment: yes, I have a PostgresTool that I've created myself and is a class.

Comment: Well how are we supposed to know whats going on in there. The error make it quite obvious, `$this->handlers` is not what you think

Comment: It is certainly likely that the link has been closed. Make sure you are not automatically closing the link too early.

Comment: I know that and as you can see in recheck function I haven't closed connection except at the end with $pgDB->close; The only codes that is out of your sight is $this->gateUtil->recheck($row); and recheck method does nothing with db and only checks so that some strings be at right size.